# How to make a url to point on an IP?

Tags: ip, subdomain, redirect

I have got a java server running on a server with IP x.x.x.x also got a webserver running on a server with IP y.y.y.y.

What i'm trying to achive here is to make a subdomain on my webserver like
auth.mydomain.com, and use it on the client side so clients will connect to my server with IP x.x.x.x. by using the subdomain.

Tried to add a redirect through c-panel by editing the subdomain, but there was no success!
I have read somethings about editing record.

Any ideas?
(Should I use xampp server on my server to "host" the subdomain?)

Answer (score 1):

Create an `a` record for the subdomain and point it to your webserver (listening on port 80) then when the authentication is done have your application redirect them to wherever... (providing you have auth on this too)?

Why not have the application have a front end sitting on a webserver?

Comment: Well on the server i got login and game servers running.
So client when they press login first login server handles their info (on port z) and if they are ok it sends those data on game server (on port Z).
So what i would like to do is on my clients file instead of using the IP x.x.x.x to connect to login server, use the auth.mydomain.com.